# Java library for parsing & building logical expressions

Tags: java

I am looking for an open source library in Java for parsing and building SQL-like expressions.

for example to evaluate validity of expressions like:

```
 "(a = x or y ) and (b != z)"
```

in addition I want to have an API for building or extending expressions.
something like:

```
Expression exp = new Expression();
exp.addCondition("a",{"x","y"},Operator.OR);
```

It's not very complicated to implement such a library, but aren't we develop in Java to enjoy collaborative development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can have [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) do this for you.

The grammatic looks very simple ( from here ) :P

Comment: Be sure to note the numerous existing SQL grammars on the sample grammar page: http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list