# javascript array parsing matching

Tags: javascript, logic, pattern-matching, expression

Let's say I have an array.

```
["red", "blue", "neon", "black", "orange"]
```

I want to evaluate whether or not a certain matching pattern is true.

I want commas to indicate OR and && to indicate AND.

```
"red&&blue" -> true
"blue&&white" -> false
"red,white" -> true
"(red&&blue),(red&&white)" -> true
"(red&&blue)&&(red&&white)" -> false
"(red&&blue)&&(red&&neon)" -> true
```

What kind of matching scheme should I use? I would like to not implement a parser from scratch, if there's any existing that would be great, but otherwise I would like the logic to work just like how it works in javascript with unlimited complexity.

I'm basically looking for something like this but for javascript:
[Java library for parsing & building logical expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425631/java-library-for-parsing-building-logical-expressions)

Comment: There are quite a few [parser generators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211111/javascript-parser-generator) for Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll almost certainly be best off writing a parser or *using* one someone's already written. As you pointed out in the comments, for this *very* constrained input, it's actually really easy:

- Split the string on the operators
- Walk through the resulting split string:

  - Validating operators
  - Converting `,` to `||`
  - Optionally validating the names
  - Replacing names with `true` (if it's in the array) or `false` (if it isn't)
- Rejoin the result into a string again
- Run the result through `eval` (since you now know it **only** has the operators you've whitelisted and the text `true` or `false`)

Here's a quick proof-of-concept: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/otEgiGu/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/otEgiGu/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Expression Thingy</title>
  <style>
    .good {
      color: green;
    }
    .bad {
      color: #d22;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var array = ["red", "blue", "neon", "black", "orange"];
      var tests = [
        {expr: "red&&blue",                 expect: true},
        {expr: "blue&&white",               expect: false},
        {expr: "red,white",                 expect: true},
        {expr: "(red&&blue),(red&&white)",  expect: true},
        {expr: "(red&&blue)&&(red&&white)", expect: false},
        {expr: "(red&&blue)&&(red&&neon)",  expect: true},
        {expr: "(red+blue)&&(red!neon)",    expectInvalid: true}
      ];
      var data;

      // Turn data into an object with named properties, to make lookups
      // faster
      data = {};
      array.forEach(function(entry) {
        data[entry] = true;
      });

      // Run the tests
      tests.forEach(runTest);

      function runTest(test) {
        var parts, invalid = false;

        // Get an array of tokens: We'll get `(`, `)`, `,`, `&&`, whitespace, or a name in each array slot
        parts = test.expr.match(/&&|,|\(|\)|\s+|[^()&,]+/g);

        // Validate the operators and turn the names into "true" or "false"
        parts.forEach(function(part, index) {
          switch (part) {
            case ",":
              // Valid operator, replace with ||
              parts[index] = "||";
              break;
            case "&&":
            case "(":
            case ")":
              // Valid operator
              break;
            default:
              // Name or whitespace
              if (!part.replace(/\s+/g, "")) {
                // Whitespace
              }
              else {
                // Name, validate it -- obviously apply whatever rule works
                // for your data, the rule below allows A-Z, $, and _ in
                // the first position and those plus digits in subsequent
                // positions.
                if (!/^[A-Za-z$_][A-Za-z0-9$_]*$/.test(part)) {
                  // Invalid
                  display("Invalid name: " + part, test.expectInvalid);
                  invalid = true;
                }
                else {
                  // Valid, replace it
                  parts[index] = data[part] ? "true" : "false";
                }
              }
              break;
          }
        });
        if (!invalid) {
          // Now we know parts only has valid stuff we can trust in it, rejoin
          // and eval it
          result = !!eval(parts.join(""));
          display(test.expr + ": Got " + result + ", expected " + test.expect, result === test.expect);
        }
      }

      function display(msg, good) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        if (typeof good !== "undefined") {
          p.className = good ? "good" : "bad";
        }
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You'd probably want to massage the validation rules at least a bit.

---

**Old answer**, largely assumed you could trust the input:

It's easy to turn those inputs into valid JavaScript expressions. Then you can either:

1. Use a parser someone else has already written, <s>[like this one](https://github.com/silentmatt/js-expression-eval) (details in [this blog post](http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/))</s> *(that one doesn't seem to support `&&` and `||`, though perhaps you could extend it to)*, or
2. Convert the array into object properties and use `eval`. **Never** trust `eval` on inputs that aren't safe or can't be *made* safe. But if the inputs are safe or can be made safe, `eval` is fine.

Assuming the values in the array are valid JavaScript identifiers, you can turn those expressions into valid JavaScript expressions simply by changing `,` to `||`:

```
str = str.replace(/,/g, "||");
```

Similarly, this turns that array into an object with those named properties:

```
var obj = {};
data.forEach(function(entry) {
    obj[entry] = true;
});
```

...which you'd presumably then pass into the expression evaluator.

If you're going the `eval` route, you have to do a bit more prep on the string, turning `"(red&&blue),(red&&white)"` into `'(obj["red"]&&obj["blue"])||(obj["red"]&&obj["white"])'`, like this:

```
str = str.replace(/,/g, "||").replace(/\b([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\b/g, 'obj["$1"]');
```

I won't do an example using an expression evaluator library, but here are the basics with `eval`: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/eLosIFoN/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/eLosIFoN/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Expression Thingy</title>
  <style>
    .good {
      color: green;
    }
    .bad {
      color: #d22;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var data = ["red", "blue", "neon", "black", "orange"];
      var tests = [
        {expr: "red&&blue",                 expect: true},
        {expr: "blue&&white",               expect: false},
        {expr: "red,white",                 expect: true},
        {expr: "(red&&blue),(red&&white)",  expect: true},
        {expr: "(red&&blue)&&(red&&white)", expect: false},
        {expr: "(red&&blue)&&(red&&neon)",  expect: true}
      ];
      var obj;

      // Turn data into an object with named properties
      obj = {};
      data.forEach(function(entry) {
        obj[entry] = true;
      });

      // Turn the expressions into eval strings
      tests.forEach(createEvalString);

      // Run the tests
      tests.forEach(runTest);

      function createEvalString(test) {
        test.evalStr = test.expr.replace(/,/g, "||").replace(/\b([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\b/g, 'obj["$1"]');
      }

      function runTest(test) {
        var result;

        display(test.evalStr);
        result = !!eval(test.evalStr); // Relies on us closing over `obj`
        display(test.expr + ": Got " + result + ", expected " + test.expect, result === test.expect);
      }

      function display(msg, good) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        if (typeof good !== "undefined") {
          p.className = good ? "good" : "bad";
        }
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

That's just a starting point. For one thing, you'll want to check the strings carefully before transforming them and using them with `eval`.

Comment: Thank you very much but the inputs are not safe which is problematic.

Comment: I thought of an idea, what do you think?: Split each expression with (),&& one by one until you get to the smallest component. Then for each part check whether or not it's in the array. Give it a true or false value. Once that's done rejoin them all again with the same values you split before. Then you should be able to safely eval (as it's only true/false expressions)

Comment: @Harry: You inspired me to see how easy that was. It's really, really easy, see the updated answer. Also, we should clean up these comments as they no longer add anything.

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, here's a more reliable way to do the job:

- go to http://pegjs.majda.cz/online
- enter the grammar for your mini-language
- test the grammar with your examples
- click "download parser"

That's basically all about that - no need to reinvent wheels.

For the examples you've posted the grammar can be like this:

```
{
var props = ["red", "blue", "neon", "black", "orange"]; 
}


start
  = additive

additive
  = left:multiplicative "," right:additive { return left || right }
  / multiplicative

multiplicative
  = left:primary "&&" right:multiplicative { return left && right }
  / primary

primary
  = atom
  / "(" additive:additive ")" { return additive; }

atom 
  = letters:[a-z]+ { return props.indexOf(letters.join("")) >= 0 }
```

Comment: Nifty! I couldn't resist seeing how hard it was to implement Harry's idea. It was trivial. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this particular case, can be solved with this simple function

```
var whiteList = ["red", "blue", "neon", "black", "orange"];
function evaluator(inputString) {
    var data = whiteList.reduce(function(previous, current) {
        return previous.split(current).join("####");
    }, inputString);
    data = data.replace(",", "||").replace(/[a-zA-Z]+/g, "false");
    return eval(data.replace(/####/g, "true"));
}
```

[Sample run](http://jsfiddle.net/Ywmn5/1/), with testcases (Thanks to @T.J. Crowder :)

Comment: Stupid question but why do you use `####`?

Comment: @Harry That was just a placeholder. I could have set that as `true` itself, but `[a-zA-Z]+` will change all the `true`s as well to `false`.